# Android Studio - how to open another fragment from navigation drawer

Tags: android, sdk

In my navigation drawer I have to selections: 1)Laptop 2)Desktop
How can I open another fragment when I click on Desktop? Sorry, I am new in Android Programming
I have also visited the other questions about this in stackoverflow, but they still do not work
Thanks

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentLaptop();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentDesktop();
            break;
    }
    transaction
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the official example? http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip

Comment: yes, but there is only one fragment. I need an example with 2 Fragments. I am searching for days for a solution!

Comment: There's one Fragment _class_. If you look at the `selectItem(int position)` method, it demonstrates how to perform a `FragmentTransaction`. All you need beyond that is to determine which `Fragment` to load given the `position` parameter. They just use one class for simplicity's sake. You can have as many different ones as you want, but the basic principle is the same.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks. But what should I write in the Fragment Classes?

Comment: Well, in your case, the Fragments are going to act pretty much like Activities. One difference, though, is that instead of an `onCreate()` method, you'll setup the Layouts and Views in the `onCreateView()` method. And instead of calling `setContentView()`, `onCreateView()` `return`s the Fragment's layout as a View object inflated from your xml file.

Comment: ok thank you. I have created a second Fragment Automatically (Android Studio created it for me) and it gives me an error by: `fragment = new FragmentLaptop()`it says `incompatible types. Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment; Found: com.example.ali.navdrawerapp.FragmentTweaks`....how can I fix that?

Comment: It sounds like your imports aren't consistent. That is, you've got this line in one class: `import android.app.Fragment;` and this line in another: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`. Pick one. They need to be the same in both classes. Use the support package if you want your app to run on older versions of Android, otherwise you can use the other one.

Comment: I don't have `import android.app.Fragment`. I only have `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` what else can it be?

Comment: What is `FragmentLaptop` a subclass of? That is, what does it `extends`?

Comment: `FragmentLaptop`is a Fragment Class and it `extends Fragment`

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to post code. I'm not familiar with Android Studio.

Comment: I have posted the code. Pls check it

Comment: You said the error was on this line: `fragment = new FragmentLaptop()`. This line is not in the code you posted.

Comment: sry, i updated it. the error is still on this line two lines `fragment = new FragmentLaptop()`and `fragment = new FragmentDesktop`

Comment: Are your Activity and those Fragment classes in separate files? If so, make sure they _all_ import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. If they do, try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: thanks man! you're a genius! But know I have on more problem :( It isn't open the other fragment and it isn't closing the navigation drawer. Where should I wirte the code I've posted? because the method I've posted is never used

Comment: It needs to be called in the `onItemClick()` method of the `OnItemClickListener` that you set for the drawer's `ListView`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks man! But now I have another issue -.-
When the user opens the app, it shows you the standard screen (FragmentLaptop) and then the user swipes to right and selects FragmentDesktop...this works..thanks a lot! But now the issue: When the user is on FragmentDesktop and presses Back...The app shows on FragmentDesktop the content (for example TextView) of FragmentLaptop. The app should not do that. How can I fix that?

Comment: @MikeM. and also when I am on the FragmentLaptop screen and press back and select FragmentDesktop, the app shows me the content (textView) from FragmentLaptop on FragmentDesktop...that means I have the normal content from FragmentDesktop plus the content of FragmentLaptop...where can be the problem?

Comment: You should post another question for this, and mark this one as solved (if you can; I dunno. I've not asked a question, and don't know how it works.) That said, are you using the `add()` method, or the `replace()` method on your `FragmentTransaction`?

Comment: I do not have the `add()`method. I only have `replace()`and `addToBackStack()` and `commit()`
the code looks like this: 
`fragment = new FragmentDesktop()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
break;`

Comment: I assume you're using a `FrameLayout` for the `Fragment` container. Do you have any `View`s inside of it in the xml? How is the initial `Fragment` loaded? In code, or in a `<fragment>` element in xml?

Comment: yes. I have a textView and a Button in FragmentDesktop and a textView in FragmentLaptop
Well, In activity_main i have a `<fragment>`element and in fragment_laptop I have a textview, as mentioned

Comment: I would guess that the statically defined `<fragment>` is persisting. Take it out, and only use dynamic `FragmentTransaction`s in code.

Comment: ok but the problem is, that the id of this `<fragment>`element is used in MyActivity two times. what should I do?

Comment: Take them out and load them dynamically with `FragmentTransaction`s. If you want to be changing Fragments in code, you shouldn't have any defined statically in the layout.

Comment: ok, but what shall I do then with this lines `mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer;

mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));`

Comment: Either keep a reference to the created `Fragment` with variable, or create it with a Tag and use `FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag()`. Also, I don't mean to be rude, but you really need to post new questions. Stack Overflow is not an interactive debugging service, and long strings of comments like this are very frowned-upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position)`needs to be called in `onItemClick(...)` where you have the listener of the list
like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
            onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
```